# ASP.net core how to map post and put request route to HTTP://site/area/controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'm going to map my post and put request to URL `http://site/area/controller`,
and I used `HttpPost` and `HttpPut` attributes.

But when I post data to server, it returned *404 Not found*.

My code:

```
public class ApplicationsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IApplicationService _applicationService;

    public ApplicationsController(IApplicationService applicationService)
    {
        _applicationService = applicationService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ApplicationQuery query)
    {
        var permissionNodes = await _applicationService.SelectePagedApplicationsAsync(query);
        ViewData["Query"] = query;
        return View(permissionNodes.Data);
    }

    [HttpPost("/Applications")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ApplicationViewModel model)
    {
        var app = Mapper.Map<Application>(model);
        var result = await _applicationService.CreateApplicationAsync(app);
        ViewData["ServiceResult"] = result;
        return View(nameof(Edit));
    }

    [HttpPut("/Applications")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(ApplicationViewModel model)
    {
        var app = Mapper.Map<Application>(model);
        var result = await _applicationService.CreateApplicationAsync(app);
        ViewData["ServiceResult"] = result;
        return View(nameof(Edit));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id)
    {
        var result = await _applicationService.FindApplicationAsync(new ApplicationQuery
        {
            Id = id
        });
        var model = Mapper.Map<ApplicationViewModel>(result.Data);
        return View(model);
    }
```

What is the way to make MVC map my request to my action?

Comment: You've set your action for `http://site/Applications` url

Comment: that was the default route for HTTPGET, i thought that the httpPost attribute will get higher prioity than default route.

Comment: you can change `[HttpPost("/Applications")]` to `[HttpPost("/area/controller")]`. But it's better if you use RouteAttribute on your controller

Comment: shows exception:
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Create' was not found. The following locations were searched:

Comment: That's another problem and has nothing to do with routing. It can't find view file for Create.

Comment: I've a debug break point in my action code, which never triggered.so,i think the route is still not currect. I've tried add the Create.cshtml file,and  I get to that file result without execute my action.

Comment: I've a debug break point in my action code, which never triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing token assignments of the routes in question.

[Token replacement in route templates ([controller], [action], [area])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

> For convenience, attribute routes support token replacement by enclosing a token in square-braces (`[`, `]`). The tokens `[action]`, `[area]`, and `[controller]` will be replaced with the values of the action name, area name, and controller name from the action where the route is defined.

Seeing as you want to isolate those routes to only the `POST` and `PUT` endpoints update the routes accordingly

```
public class ApplicationsController : Controller {

    //...code removed for brevity

    //Matches POST /{area}/applications
    [HttpPost("[area]/[controller]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]ApplicationViewModel model) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    //Matches PUT /{area}/applications
    [HttpPut("[area]/[controller]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]ApplicationViewModel model) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

The above also assumes that the proper configuration has already been done in relation to areas

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)